# get a portable function from Polynomial.fit()

Tags: python, numpy

I took voltage readings from a LiPo battery discharging every 5 minutes - this gave me
~2700 data points. I pulled them into numpy with the hopes that I could find a polynomial function that would take a voltage and (based on the discharge curve) return the percentage of the battery remaining; in an ideal situation, f(3.3) = 0 and f(4.2) = 100. After a few rounds of modeling I found that an 8th order function worked pretty well (though it goes off the rails if you feed it more than 4.2, which is fine, I expected that and I'll just clamp the results between 0 and 100). Eventually I want to take the coefficients over to a C++ program which means I need to get the "real" coefficients for x^0...x^8. But I can't quite seem to get those values lined up.

Here's my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

x = df.voltage
y = df.percentage

p_fitted = P.fit(x, y, 8)

# this next line outputs this:
# [a] + [b]*x - [c]*x^2 etc
print(p_fitted)

def percentage(voltage):
    # I took the [a], [b], [c] values, eg, [a, b, -c]
    coefficients = [ ... ]
    total = 0
    for i, coef in enumerate(coefficients):
        total += coef * voltage ** i
    return total
```

Running `p_fitted(3.64)` returns `49.139` which is pretty much right where it should be; running `percentage(3.64)` returns `2376004.025` which is definitely NOT where it should be.

I've tried a few things - rather than use the function that is shown when I `print(p_fitted)` for coefficients, I tried `p_fitted.convert().coef` which gives me astronomically large coefficients, and a similarly large (incorrect) answer. Having seen a note that those coefficients are reversed, I tried to reverse the list produced by the `.convert().coef` method and the result was still comically large and wrong. I even manually copied down the formula from the first `print` statement and hard-coded it against `3.64` - got the same (wrong) answer as what `percentage(3.64)` returned so at least I know the function does what it's supposed to do. Obviously I'm not getting the correct numbers to plug into the formula but I'm scratching my head on what I *do* need to do to get those numbers. Is there a way to get an actually portable function out of this class?

Comment: Your coefficient are reversed. You should do `total += coef * voltage ** (8-i)`

Comment: I would advice to use `polyfit` ie `np.polyfit(x,y,8)` those should be your coefficients

Comment: So I got a lot closer with polyfit - the coefficients provided by that yielded 62.459 compared to 48.970 from the model (`model = np.poly1d(p_fitted)`). I'm guessing that because some of the coefficients are so huge - eg. `-2.37776887e+08` - even the tiniest variation ends up with massive differences. Any way to output even more significant digits than just the 8?

Comment: Those coefficients are too huge. Better fit all the models from degree=1 to 8 and pick the model with the lowest `mse`.

Comment: i guess my confusion is that the numpy docs (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) say that `Polynomial.fit` is preferred since v1.4, and yet they seem to give wildly different coefficients. I thought based on the docs they were basically the same thing.

Comment: I believe the api has some conversion to make. Ie call .convert() to get the same results. I might be wrong though. It's been long since I last used these functions